# VB.Net Initialization inside loop

Tags: vb.net

code1

```
while
    dim number as integer = 0
    'some code here
end while
```

code2

```
dim number as integer
while 
     number = 0
    'some code here
end while
```

What is the difference in code 1 and code 2 in terms of speed?
What else is their difference?
What is the best practice to use? thank you

Comment: If that is truly the place where you have a bottleneck in the performance of your system, congratulations. However, I seriously doubt that it is. If performance actually matters, start by setting goals and then writing clean, understandable code. Then *measure* the performance. Then, if it doesn't meet the goals, *profile* the code to find out where the bottlenecks are and then work on improving those places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In code 1, your variable's scope is constrained to the `while`-block.

In code 2, your variable's scope goes beyond the `while`-block. For example if you define your `while` block within a function, the scope of the variable is the whole function.

You can note the difference if you have the same variable within multiple blocks:

```
while
    dim number as integer = 0

    x = number // x is 0
    number = 1
end while

while
    dim number as integer = 0

    x = number // x is 0
end while
```

This code is fine, where as the following

```
dim number as integer = 0
while
    x = number // x is 0
    number = 1
end while

while
    x = number // x is 1
end while
```

Both ways are fine. Speaking of performance - do not care, if you need to improve the performance of your code you will most likely need to touch a different place. Things like this are therefore often called "micro-optimizations".

Speaking of practice, it is usually best to define the variable as close to its use as possible. So if you only need the variable (and its state) within your while-loop, define it there. If you need to read the value after the while-loop, define it outside. If you use a tool like ReSharper it will even suggest to move your definition to the inner scope (here the `while` loop) if you place it outside and do not use it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

There should be no difference in speed of the 2 approaches. the compiler will optimize this for you. You can check the resultant [IL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) code using [Ildasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The "best practice" is to use the [smallest possible scope](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56585/where-do-you-declare-variables-the-top-of-a-method-or-when-you-need-them), i.e. code 2.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't care about speed difference between these two. It will be extremely small (if any!).

Other differences? Second code makes `number` accessible after `while` loop, which may or may not what you want.

General rule: keep variables at the smallest possible scope, which means if you only need the variable within loop, declare it within loop. If you need it's value to be accessible when loop ends, declare it before loop.